# AWS EventBridge Bus-to-Bus routing with Rules and Input Transformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, event-bus, aws-event-bridge

I am connecting 3rd-party applications like Shopify via AWS partner event sources to EventBridge. The 3rd-party events are emitted on an application-specific custom EventBus  and each event triggers and event rule (on that bus) that transforms the 3rd-party event into a common format start the execution of common StepFunction. That means the event bus, event rule and target (state machine) are hardly-coupled resources.

AWS EventBridge [supports bus-to-bus event](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-bus-to-bus-event-routing-with-amazon-eventbridge/) routing. That means events on a custom event bus can be forwarded to the default event bus. Then, on the default event bus, an event rule can trigger the common StepFunction. That would mean 3rd-party apps are only loosely-coupled with shared resources because their events are jus re-emitted on the default event bus where the actual hard coupling takes place.

For whatever reason, the input transformer of events via an event rule **is not possible** if the event target is another event bus. That would mean I have to move all 3rd-party event transformations from their respective custom event buses into rules on the default event bus.

Of course, I could have a Lambda function as common target for each custom event bus that simply re-emits the events on the default event bus. But, are there any feasible and/or cheaper workarounds?

Hopefully this post will catch the attention of some AWS employees who can tell us if this feature is expected in the near future.

Comment: Just encountered the same issue. What did you end up doing as a solution?

Comment: I'm still hoping this feature will be implemented by AWS any time soon. As workaround I create rules on the 3rd-party event buses that trigger the same State Machine as on the default bus. So I ended up hardly-coupling resources for now.